# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'str' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that is outputting content when I do a console.log, however when I try to do a .str.replace operation on this variable it says it is undefined!

```
var thisbuttonDownContents = document.getElementById("Frm" + frm + 'Results');

if (thisbuttonDownContents != null) {
  thisbuttonDownContents = thisbuttonDownContents.textContent;
  console.log(thisbuttonDownContents); //This outputs: West Ter -  Selected 
  var test = thisbuttonDownContents.textContent.str.replace("Selected", ""); 
  //^ This gives the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'str' of undefined
```

I have another function in this javascript that I have copied and pasted this code from and it works fine!  The fact that console.log actually returns a value shows that the element exists and is not undefined. I have tried typecasting toString and that makes no difference.

Comment: `thisbuttonDownContents.textContent.str.replace("Selected","");`  what do you mean by str here, shouldn't it be `thisbuttonDownContents.textContent.replace("Selected","");`  ?

Comment: If I take the .str out it still gives the same error. What gets me is this is a direct copy paste of another function in the same file with .str.replace and it works in the other function.

Comment: `thisbuttonDownContents` already is `.textContent`. It doesn't have yet another `.textContent`.

Comment: Yes, trying to get .textContent twice was the problem.  Thanks!! I was playing with this one for hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
thisbuttonDownContents = thisbuttonDownContents.textContent;
```

you are **replacing** the DOM element you previously had by the `string` contained in the DOM element's `textContent` property.

Obviously  `thisbuttonDownContents` then is no longer a DOM element, so it doesn't have a  `textContent` property any longer.

But even if you wipe out that line, `replace` is a function that is called directly on a variable containing a string, or a string literal, so, as others pointed out, it would have to be

```
var test = thisbuttonDownContents.textContent.replace("Selected","");
```

or, if you insist on the problematic line mentioned in the introduction,

```
var test = thisbuttonDownContents.replace("Selected","");
```